# Sorting an ArrayList without using 'Collections.sort'

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

We have to make an ArrayList that will take values for as long as the user wants them to and then put them in order. Other questions with this type of problem typically have using Collections.sort as a solution, but I would rather use something else to understand ArrayLists better.

My program is taking values and printing out the ones that I pre-added to the array but something very strange is happening where it prints out duplicates of the numbers the user inputs instead of putting them in order.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Orderedarraylist {

    static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list.add(7);
        list.add(178);
        list.add(12);
        list.add(9);

        System.out.println("Enter any number.");
        int n = scan.nextInt();

        list.add(n);

        System.out.println("Enter any number.");
        int b = scan.nextInt();

        list.add(b);

        while ((n >= 0) && (b >= 0)) {
            System.out.println("Enter another number or press 2 to exit.");
            int x = scan.nextInt();
            if (x == 2) {
                break;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++) {
                if (x > list.get(i)) {
                    list.add(x);
                } else {
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
        //something is happening in here that prints multiples of the numbers. it doesn't print the first set of values that way
        //but it also doesn't print them in order.. 
        System.out.println("Here is your list: " + list);
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove `else i++;`... You don't need to do that - the for loop already does it on its own

Comment: Also, do you really want to add x into the end of the list for "every number" it's greater than?

Comment: You don't need to use Collections.sort()' here. You just want to maintain order, and that list interface takes care and remove else i++.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/263115/when-is-it-okay-to-edit-answers-for-code-formatting

Comment: @Tom We are not doing edit war here and the change was not about personal preference but about consistency: `.add (7)` in one place and `.get(i)` in another, `n>=0` and somewhere else `i < list.size()` and so on. So yes, I have thrown it into the code formatter to make it more readable and I think it was the right decision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `Collections.sort()`' here. You just want to maintain order, and that `list interface` takes care and remove `else i++.` If x is greater than multiple elements in the list, then your code adding `x` multiple times thats why you are getting duplicates here.

```
if (x == 2) break;

for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++) {
    if (x > list.get(i)) {
        list.add(i, x);
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding all numbers to the end of the list with the add(x) call. Instead, you need to insert it into the current position with add(i, x).

After it is added, you need to break out of the loop. Instead, you are adding it repeatedly to the end of the list.

So you want:

```
if(x>list.get(i)) {
    list.add(i, x);
    break;
}
```